# How to set an entities attribute via relationship?

Tags: swift, core-data, entity, relationship

I have the following entities and relationship

[image]

I want to be able to set an exercise to have a nil result for its routine name relationship, if that makes sense? so that it can later be set as a routine name when the routine entity is formed.

My question is, how do you set this sort of attribute up? I am trying the following code but it causes a fatal crash:

```
userExercise.usersroutine?.name = nil
```

My logic being that i take the exercise and follow the relationship to the name property and set it to nil?

Thanks for any correction and clarification on my logic

**EDIT: Added my existing exercise and routine save functions**

```
    func createExercise() {
    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }
   if let userExercise = userExercise {
        userExercise.name = userExerciseName.text
        userExercise.sets = Int64(userSetsCount)
        userExercise.reps = Int64(userRepsCount)
        userExercise.weight = Double(self.userExerciseWeight.text!)!
        userExercise.id = UUID().uuidString
        userExercise.routine = nil
    }
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Routine Creation:

```
    func createRoutine() {

    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }
    let userRoutine = UserRoutine(context: managedObjectContext)
    userRoutine.name = workoutNameTextfield.text

    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Current Fetch Request:

```
    fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
```

Comment: This is because your usersroutine value itself is nil & you are trying to set name on top of it. Makes sense? First try to assign a value to routine & then set name to nil if required.

Comment: I understand, so what would be the correct way? to simply use userExercise.usersroutine = nil  until i have the name to set?

Comment: Can you explain what type of relationship you want to have between Routine & Exercise, so that I better understand your problem & give a workable solution.

Comment: 1 routine will contain many exercises, but an exercise will only belong to one routine, I want the routine builder to look at the exercises and import all the exercises with nil in the relationship into it, as they havent been assigned to other routines, and then i can save the routine applying its name to those exercises replacing the nil, creating a routine with attributed exercises. The routine doesnt exist when the exercises are created, it is created afterward and its name is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the implementation below I'have created some exercises and routines. Also read comments in code, this will help you figure out how to go about it.

Function to add a new exercise

```
func createExercise(weight: Int16, respetitions: Int16, name: String, routine: Routine?)->Exercise? {
    let context = getMainContext()
    let exercise = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Exercise", into: context) as! Exercise
    exercise.setValue(weight, forKey: "weight")
    exercise.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    exercise.setValue(respetitions, forKey: "rep")

    do {
        try context.save()
        return exercise
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("unable to Ssavve")
    }
}
```

Function to add a new routine

```
func createRoutine(name: String, exercises:[Exercise]) {
    let context = getMainContext()
    let routine = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Routine", into: context) as! Routine
    routine.name = name

    //Iterate over Exercise objects & check if routine is nil. 
   //Here if routine is not nil it menas your exercise is already assigned to a routine. 
   //If routine is nil assign routine.addToRelationship(<#T##value: Exercise##Exercise#>) and Also assign routine to the execise.

     do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            fatalError("unable to Ssavve")
        }

}
```

Function to get main NSManagedObjectContext on which we can perform core-data actions

```
func getMainContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Below, First I create few exercises without any relationship to routines

> "The routine doesnt exist when the exercises are created, it is created afterward and its name is set"

and then create routines by passing some exercises ([You can refer to other answer on how to fetch exercises with routine as nil values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894167/616296))

```
func initializer() {
        //I'm adding exercises first without routines
        let ex1 = self.createExercise(weight: 10, respetitions: 4, name: "Exercise1", routine: nil)
        let ex2 = self.createExercise(weight: 5, respetitions: 10, name: "Exercise2", routine: nil)
        let ex3 = self.createExercise(weight: 20, respetitions: 2, name: "Exercise3", routine: nil)
        let ex4 = self.createExercise(weight: 5, respetitions: 10, name: "Exercise2", routine: nil)

        self.createRoutine(name: "Routine 1", exercises: [ex1!, ex2!]) //You can pass all the exercises or use fetch request to query exercises with routine as nil
        self.createRoutine(name: "Routine 2", exercises: [ex3!, ex4!])

        self.createRoutine(name: "Routine 3", exercises: [ex1!, ex2!]) //This routine shall not be adding any execises as they are already added to othe routines
    }
```

Updating create routine Function to query results of UserExercise which has usersroutine as nil

```
func createRoutine() {

    guard let managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext else { return }
    let userRoutine = UserRoutine(context: managedObjectContext)
    userRoutine.name = workoutNameTextfield.text

//Getting nil value User Exercises        
    let request: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
                request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "usersroutine == nil")
                do {
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                    let queryResults = try context.fetch(request)

                    //I like to check the size of the returned results!
                    print ("num of results = \(queryResults.count)")

                    //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
                    for exercise in queryResults as [NSManagedObject] {
                        //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
                        print("Exercise NAME: \(exercise.value(forKey: "name"))")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error with request: \(error)")
                }


        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: im with you up until it comes to iterating over exercises to add them / change their nil routine to the routine im saving, i cant figure out how to implement that part, im using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to i assume using that to query nil exercises is the right method, but not sure how to do so. Also what type of attribute is needed in the core data entity to store an exercises array?

Comment: also the getUnmappedExercise causes so many errors in my VC as its now a function as opposed to the code in the OP, is it not possible to simply edit that code to perform the task?

Comment: I added that function for you to understand just implementation part. See the edit, I have removed func, try to use this code and tell me if you see any results(Print statements).

Comment: im getting the error Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to specified type 'NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise>', i kept the fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {  from my previous code as the VC needed it for reference, is this the cause?

Comment: I don't see any compile time issues on Xcode 8.0, I checked.

Comment: Also See I have updated func createRoutine() to check for exercises with nil routines.

Comment: replied in chat

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem that you should need to use the `name` attribute at all. This attribute should be used for storing the actual name of the `UserRoutine` and not for anything relationship based.

The relationships between entities in Core Data don't rely on a particular attribute of an entity, but between the entities themselves.

> "I want the routine builder to look at the exercises and import all the exercises with nil in the relationship into it"

So...

Create a fetch request to fetch all the entities of `UserExercise` that don't have a related `UserRoutine` (i.e. where `userroutine` is nil).

```
let orphanedExerciseFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserExercises")
orphanedExerciseFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userroutine == nil)
```

Execute this fetch request to get an array of UserExercises (with no related routine)

```
let orphanedExercises = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(orphanedExerciseFetchRequest())
```

> "creating a routine with attributed exercises"

Set the fetched `UserExercise` entitiy's property `userRoutine` to your routine (and don't forget to save the changes in your managed object context).

```
myRoutine.userexercises = orphanedExercises
```

Later, if you want to get the exercises for a particular routine:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "UserExercises")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userroutine == %@", someUserRoutine)
```

Comment: Note: Not written with Xcode, so may be some typos etc. but hopefully this will help you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, i have updated my OP with my current fetch request, can this be modified to incorporate this code or does it need a separate method?

Comment: Tried the following but im getting fatal errors? fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<UserExercise> = {
let orphanedExerciseFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UserExercise> = UserExercise.fetchRequest()
orphanedExerciseFetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userroutine == nil")
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: orphanedExerciseFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
return fetchedResultsController}()